# ListView Didn't show When ArrayList have 2 or more data

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

```
    for (int qt = 1; qt == QRLOG; qt++)
    {
        String qrNew = libraryData.getString("CRsaves" + qt, "~~~");
        String qrNewT = libraryData.getString("CRsaves" + qt + "T", "00:00:00");
        String qrNewD = libraryData.getString("CRsaves" + qt + "D", "0000/00/00");
        String qrNewTD = qrNewT + "---" + qrNewD;
        qrLists.add(qrNew);
        qrTimes.add(qrNewTD);
    }

    for (int bt = 1; bt == BRlOG; bt++)
    {
        String brNew = libraryData.getString("BRsaves" + bt, "~~~");
        String brNewT = libraryData.getString("BRsaves" + bt + "T", "00:00:00");
        String brNewD = libraryData.getString("BRsaves" + bt + "D", "0000/00/00");
        String brNewTD = brNewT + "---" + brNewD;
        barLists.add(brNew);
        barTimes.add(brNewTD);
    }
```

> QRLOG is count data of CR saves, BRLOG is count of BR saves
>    "libraryData" is a SharedPreferences

```
            if (position == 1)
            {
                bqrTime.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, qrTimes));
                bqrList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, qrLists));
                headB = 1;
                bqrList.setEnabled(true);
                bqrList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bqrTime.setEnabled(true);
                bqrTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                showPicture.setEnabled(false);
                deleteSave.setEnabled(false);
            }
            if (position == 2)
            {
                bqrTime.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, barTimes));
                bqrList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, barLists));
                headB = 2;
                bqrList.setEnabled(true);
                bqrList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                bqrTime.setEnabled(true);
                bqrTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                showPicture.setEnabled(false);
                deleteSave.setEnabled(false);
            }
```

> There is Listing of Datas...

```
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/bqrList"
            android:layout_width="146dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/bqrTime"
            android:layout_width="238dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true" />
```

> There is The xml File

**If data Counts are 1 the ListView is Showing data Without any an error..
But The counts are 2 or more the ListView is didn't Showing the datas.. ://
I'll crazy help me please..**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this for loop

```
for (int qt = 1; qt <= QRLOG; qt++)
{
    String qrNew = libraryData.getString("CRsaves" + qt, "~~~");
    String qrNewT = libraryData.getString("CRsaves" + qt + "T", "00:00:00");
    String qrNewD = libraryData.getString("CRsaves" + qt + "D", "0000/00/00");
    String qrNewTD = qrNewT + "---" + qrNewD;
    qrLists.add(qrNew);
    qrTimes.add(qrNewTD);
}

for (int bt = 1; bt <= BRlOG; bt++)
{
    String brNew = libraryData.getString("BRsaves" + bt, "~~~");
    String brNewT = libraryData.getString("BRsaves" + bt + "T", "00:00:00");
    String brNewD = libraryData.getString("BRsaves" + bt + "D", "0000/00/00");
    String brNewTD = brNewT + "---" + brNewD;
    barLists.add(brNew);
    barTimes.add(brNewTD);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the loop, you should have `!=`  **not** `==`.

```
for (int qt = 0; qt != QRLOG; qt++) {
   // Use qt+1 instead of qt because I initilized it with 0
  }
for (int bt = 0; bt != BRlOG; bt++) {
    //Same for here
  }
```

**In your code**

if you put `QRLOG = 1` and `BRLOG = 1`, the loop runs and shows things because `qt` and `bt` were initilized with 1. But not for any other value.

Pretty lame Issue.

Please check your code throughly before posting.